# Calculating the Angle Between Two vectors Using Dot Product

Tags: c++, winapi, vector, directx

I'm trying to calculate the angle between two vectors so that I can rotate a character in the direction of an object in 3D space. I have two vectors( character & object), loc_look, and modelPos respectively. For simplicity's sake I am only trying to rotate along the up axis...yaw. loc_look = D3DXVECTOR3 (0, 0, 1), modelPos = D3DXVECTOR3 (0, 0, 15);

I have written this code which seems to be the correct calculations. My problem arises, seemingly, because the rotation I apply to the character's look vector(loc_look) exceeds the value of the object's position (modelPos). Here is my code:

```
BOOL CEntity::TARGET()   
{   
    if(graphics.m_model->m_enemy)   
    {   
        D3DXVECTOR3 modelPos = graphics.m_model->position;   
        D3DXVec3Normalize(&modelPos, &modelPos);   

        //D3DXVec3Normalize(&loc_look, &loc_look);   
        float dot = D3DXVec3Dot(&loc_look, &modelPos);   
        float yaw = acos(dot);   
        BOOL neg = (loc_look.x > modelPos.x) ? true : false;   
        switch ( neg )   
        {   
        case false:   
            Yaw(yaw);   
            return true;   
        case true:   
            Yaw(-yaw);   
            return true;   
        }          
    }   
    else  
        return false;   
}
```

I rotate the character's orientation matrix with the following code:

```
void CEntity::CalculateOrientationMatrix(D3DXMATRIX *orientationMatrix)   

{    

D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotY, &loc_up, loc_yaw);   

D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&loc_look, &loc_look, &rotY);   

D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&loc_right, &loc_right, &rotY);   


D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotX, &loc_right, loc_pitch);   

D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&loc_look, &loc_look, &rotX);   

D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&loc_up, &loc_up, &rotX);   


D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotZ, &loc_look, loc_roll);    

D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&loc_up, &loc_up, &rotZ);   

D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&loc_right, &loc_right, &rotZ);   

*orientationMatrix *= rotX * rotY * rotZ;   


orientationMatrix->_41 = loc_position.x;   

orientationMatrix->_42 = loc_position.y;   

orientationMatrix->_43 = loc_position.z;   


//D3DXVec3Normalize(&loc_look, &loc_look);   

SetYawPitchRoll(0,0,0); // Reset Yaw, Pitch, & Roll Amounts   

}
```

Also to note, the modelPos.x increases by 0.1 each iteration so the character will face the object as it moves along the x-axis...
Now, when I run program, in the first iteration everything is fine(I haven't rotated the character yet). On the second iteration, the loc_look.x value is greater than the modelPos.x value(I rotated the character too much using the angle specified with the dot product calculations in the TARGET function). Therefore on the second iteration my code will rotate the character left to adjust for the difference in the vectors' x values...

How can I tighten up the measurements so that I do not rotate my character's look vector by too great a value?

Comment: (0,0,1) and (0,0,15) are parallel, aren't they?

Comment: yeah...good point but the object moves to the right each iteration. the value of look.x exceeds the value of modelPos.x on the second iteration and then adjusts accordingly(rotates left). The result is a jittering affect (the character jitters right then left repeatedly).

Comment: I tried converting degrees to radians before "yawing" (Yaw((D3DXToRadian(yaw)); this prevents jittering but only because the angled is significantly reduced...the look vector never equals the modePos vector...

Comment: not sure I understood the question, but is what you want to smooth the reaction of the character? you can take a weighted average of the last few positions of the target...or google PID controller.

Comment: I would like the character vector(loc_look) to be equal to the object position (modelPos). I had planned to do this by rotating the character by an angle calculated with the dot product of the two vectors...for an unknown reason, the calculated angle is often greater than the actual angle...this causes my character to rotate too far...the jittering is caused by the compensation for the incorrect rotation applied to the character.

Comment: Are you accumulating errors by applying successive rotations to the look vector? Can't you just make the character look at the object by assigning that object's position to the look vector? Isn't what you're doing like trying to make X equal to Y by doing X += (Y - X)?  /* add the difference of Y and X to X */ instead of just X = Y?

Answer (score 4):

The dot product is the cosine of the angle between two vectors only if they are unit vectors. Please see this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_interpretation

I see you have some commented out line:

```
 //D3DXVec3Normalize(&loc_look, &loc_look);
```

But you do need to normalize both vectors.

Think about it. If the vectors are all scaled by a constant factor, the dot product gets bigger, right? And so the value going into `arccos` is bigger. But the angle is the same, so that's obviously wrong.

Comment: should the sum of each value of the vector equal 1 after being normalized? Mine do not...

Comment: Also, regarding your example **oc_look = D3DXVECTOR3 (0, 0, 1), modelPos = D3DXVECTOR3 (0, 0, 15)**  Are saying that the character is looking straight up the Z axis? and the model is also straight overhead? In this case the angle is zero. If you're concerned only with yaw, it seems like a better example would be something like looking at <1, -1, 0> and the object being at <3, 4, 0>. Is your "up axis" the Z axis?

Comment: No! The **length** of a unit vector is 1, not the sum of the components. If you take the dot product of a unit vector with itself, it should be 1.  That is to say x*x + y*y + z*z = 1. (And therefore sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z) = 1).

Comment: the origin of the object is 0, 0, 15, it moves along the x-axis, so not always parallel are the vectors

Comment: problems arise when trying to get the character's vector to follow the objects position exactly...I guess I will have to aproximate...I wanted the character to rotate with the object as it moved along the x-axis, perfectly. There is always some difference between the two vectors...anybody know of a more accurate method?

Answer (score 0):

The approximation you are talking about is normal for floating point math. You need to factor in an "epsilon" value so your character does not twitch around after the dot product is close to solved.